# variable based on two variables

Tags: php

After `foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)` i've variables like this title_1, title_2, title_3. i need to make $title equel to $title_ + $id

what i've tried

```
            $link = ${$title_ . $id};
            $title= $title_[$id];
            $title= $title_[$id];
```

the code

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
     if (preg_match('/^id_(\d*)$/', $value, $matches))
        {
    $id = $matches[1];
        if (isset($_POST['title_' . $id]))
            {
                //$link = ${$title_ . $id};
                $title= $title_[$id];
                //mysql_query("UPDATE table SET title='" . $title . "' where id='$id'");

            }
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just don't use `eval`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you want something like...

```
$link = ${$title."_" . $id};
```

or perhaps

```
${"title_" . $id};
```

see this reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Don't you mean `${'title_' . $id};`?

Comment: still getting empty ouput :(

Comment: @rabotalius what is the output of printr($_POST) in your php code when you run the script?

Comment: it actually works with                 `$link = $_POST['title_' . $id];`

Comment: @Tucker `Call to undefined function printr()`

Comment: sorry, meant: print_r   but you said you got it working>?